# Relative clause confusion: "whose company I am leaving" or "who is leaving the company"

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I came across this one in a study book:

本日、退社することになりました社長を初め皆様には本当にお世話になりました。

The translation reads 'Today I am leaving the company, and I would like to thank not only the President, but everybody.' However wouldn't a literal reading be 'I thanked everyone who is leaving the company, starting with the president'? ie implying that the president and everyone is leaving the company? Would this be more accurate:

本日、退社することになりました**私は**社長を初め皆様には本当にお世話になりました。

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two separate sentences? ...なりました。社長を...

Comment: No it appears like that. It's not a formal study guide, just some printed pages. I found where they sourced it from: http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=wohajime but perhaps it's supposed to read 本日、退社することになりまして社長を初め皆様には本当にお世話になりました or just be two sentences like you said.

Comment: It seems the submitter is commenting on the page, you could try contacting them to confirm.